# How To NOT extend selection with Box Select?

Tags: selection-tools

I'm new to Blender and am having a few hitches.

Each time I use box select on a group of vertices it extends the selection from what was previously selected.

I can avoid this by hitting <kbd>A</kbd> to deselect all before using Box Select but I was hoping there was a way to have this happen by default.

Isn't it the desired workflow to select groups of objects and move them independently and only extend the select with <kbd>Shift</kbd>?

I must be doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is understandable, yet you're approach is impractical in Blender.

Think of it this way.

When you hit <kbd>B</kbd>, you are executing an *action*: **border select**. This *action* can be aborted with <kbd>Esc</kbd> and you can choose mouseactions for deselect or select.

You are *not* using a **tool**. Once you completed the border select action, you are still using your previously selected tool (e.g. selection context). You will have to press <kbd>B</kbd> again to enter the *border select* action.

What you can do is setting the *border select with extension* to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and setting the *border select without extension* to <kbd>B</kbd>.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to open the **Blender User Preferences**. Go to the **Input** rider. You can edit the hotkeys in this context. Expand the 3D View > 3D View (Global) area.
   [image: Blender User Preferences Hotkeys]
2. Locate the entry *Border Select*, expand it and uncheck **Extend**. Now the hotkey <kbd>B</kbd> will not extend the selection with the border selection, but replace it.
   [image: Border Select Hotkey]
3. Locate the entry, which is assigned to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>. In the default case this will be *Zoom to Border* and *Set Render Boder*. Disable it by unchecking the box at the start of the row. If we don't do this, the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> will call this function first and ignore other assigned actions.
   [image: zoom to border and set render border]
4. At the end of the *3D View (Global)* List, press the button **Add New**. Enter `view3D.select_border` as the command. Set the hotkey to `Shift B` by clicking on the hotkey assigning area and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.

   > [image: add new hotkey]
5. You will now have a <kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> border select action, which will work as you explained. Note that this is set only in the 3D area. In other contexts you will have to change the hotkeys as well. If you want to keep these hotkeys for the next time starting Blender, click the <kbd>Save User Settings</kbd> button on the bottom left of the *Blender User Preferences* window.

Comment: Great explanation of how to use blender properly as well as ways to customize your workflow. Thank you.