# Border Select. How to disable the selection of closest vertex to the frame?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, edges, faces

Working with tool "Border Select" Blender automatically activates the closest to the Frame Vertex/Edge/Polygon.
[image]
Is it possible to disable this feature?

Comment: What is "closest vertex to the frame" ? Do you ask how to [disable adding to selection with Border select](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64249/how-to-not-extend-selection-with-box-select) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try and change the *3D View > Activate/Select* mouse action to *Release* instead of *Press* or *Any* that way when you click near a vertex it won't have any effect until you actually release the button.

Have in mind that this may cause a opposite side effect of selecting the vertex near where you end the selection border, if not well setup

Comment: Yes, it helped. Tnks.  https://postimg.org/image/7piu6py15/  , but now it has stopped working 'Loop Select' function.It operates by double click of the left mouse button https://postimg.org/image/5jfktzyft/

Comment: Hum yes, you have to be careful with the setups, Blender doesn't really like conflicts in the keymaps. Stuff some times stops working for no apparent reason. You'll have to try and experiment with that, it took me quite a long time to correctly set up my custom key bindings

Comment: I am also a long time customize the interface for yourself. For me, Blender is not the main instrument. So, I can afford it.  There are a lot of  hidden rocks in the way of the learning (custom keys)