# Rectangle select

Tags: selection-tools

In edit mode, border select (or rectangle select) adds to the previous selection, so in order to select only the content of the rectangle selection you are going to make, one has to deselect first if something is already selected. As a result it is a lot more time consuming. Most 2D or 3D software I've used have rectangle selections but they don't add to the previous selection by default. If you want to add to the previous selection, simply do: shift + rectangle select. It makes more sens to me but maybe I don't see the benefit of the current settings.
Is there currently a way to remove the "add to the previous selection" part of the rectangle select?

Comment: Since you say deselecting first makes it "a lot more time consuming", I'm wondering how you do the deselection. The simplest, and fastest way is pressing the A key on your keyboard. That toggles between selecting everything and deselecting everything, and if anything at all is currently selected, even a single vertex, it deselects it.

Comment: Border select (as I understand it you mean shortcut B) has Deselect feature in the user prefs. Enabling it will always make selecting with deselecting first. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64249/how-to-not-extend-selection-with-box-select. Personally I got used to deselect everything prior to any selection which depends of course but allows to get rid of changing preferences.