# Set active object with box select (blender 2.8)

Tags: selection-tools

I am looking to use the select box tool to make an object active. When I point and click on an object, it becomes active. However, when I use the select box tool on a different object, the second object is selected, but not active.

For instance (in the gif below), when I click and drag to select the light, I want it object to become the active object.

[image]

I looked at this question: [How To NOT extend selection with Box Select?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64249/how-to-not-extend-selection-with-box-select) thinking the box select may be extending my selection. But, I am not seeing the extend selection option in the 2.8 user preferences.

[image]

I am using blender 2.8, and am in object mode. I am also a blender beginner, let me know if I am misunderstanding the difference between selected and active objects.

Thanks,

Comment: I'd love to know as well. This is a big problem when moving around multiple object with varying rotations in local mode. I have to click on each object rather than using the box select. Super freaking annoying.